# Are all hyperledger transactions received by every peer regardless of channel?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I understand that peers not part of channel A cannot read the content of channel A's transactions. However I'm not clear from the docs whether every peer receives an encrypted version of every transaction, or just a digest - or if they don't see it at all. Different parts of the docs seem to contradict each other on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Each peer only receives blocks that envolve transactions corresponding to its channel.

The endorsered transactions are broadcast to the orderers.

Then, the orderers (Ordering service):

- Verify the transaction
- Order transactions chronologically by channel
- Create blocks of transactions per channel
- Send to each peer its blocks

So, each peer only receives and stores blocks wich containt transactions from its channel.